# Forecast variance of Time Series model?

Tags: variance, time-series

I'm reading the book "Forecasting: Principles and Practice" and on the exercise [page](https://otexts.com/fpp3/expsmooth-exercises.html) there are two question, 16 and 17 that I don't know how to answer. Can anyone help how I should start or post an answer (stepwise).